# JMM: Why this outcome is illegal?

Tags: java, race-condition, volatile, java-memory-model

I recently stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/master/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/jmm/advanced/AdvancedJMM_04_LosingUpdates.java) example in [jcstress](https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress):

```
@JCStressTest
@State
@Outcome(id = "10",                      expect = ACCEPTABLE,             desc = "Boring")
@Outcome(id = {"0", "1"},                expect = FORBIDDEN,              desc = "Boring")
@Outcome(id = {"9", "8", "7", "6", "5"}, expect = ACCEPTABLE,             desc = "Okay")
@Outcome(                                expect = ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING, desc = "Whoa")
public static class Volatiles {
    volatile int x;

    @Actor
    void actor1() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            x++;
        }
    }

    @Actor
    void actor2() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            x++;
        }
    }

    @Arbiter
    public void arbiter(I_Result r) {
        r.r1 = x;
    }
}
```

The author highlights that since increments are not atomic operations one cannot expect to just "lose" one increment update per loop iteration. So then all outcomes (up to `10`) except `0` and `1` are allowed (and indeed happen).

I see why `0` is not allowed: there is an HB edge between the initialization of default values of objects and the first action in every thread as stated in JLS.
[JLS 17.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html)

> The write of the default value (zero, false, or null) to each variable synchronizes-with the first action in every thread.

The author also explains how one might get the result `2`:

```
The most interesting result, "2" can be explained by this interleaving:
        Thread 1: (0 ------ stalled -------> 1)     (1->2)(2->3)(3->4)(4->5)
        Thread 2:   (0->1)(1->2)(2->3)(3->4)    (1 -------- stalled ---------> 2)
```

I understand that you cannot just "extend" the explanation above like this:

```
        Thread 1: (0 --------- stalled -----------> 1)     (1->2)(2->3)(3->4)(4->5)
        Thread 2:   (0->1)(1->2)(2->3)(3->4)(4->5)
```

Because it leads to the result `5`.
But isn't there an execution that will produce `1`?
I definitely can't think of any. But why there actually is none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's remember how `volatile` works in Java.

In Java all volatile reads and writes happen in a global order in runtime (i.e. *synchronization order* in [JLS 17.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html)).
Properties of this global order:

- it preserves the order of volatile reads/writes of every thread (in terms of [JLS 17.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html) it *is consistent with the program order*)
- it's one per execution: actions from different threads can interleave differently in different executions of the same program

A volatile read always returns the last (in this global order) volatile write to this variable (i.e. *synchronizes-with* in [JLS 17.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html)).

Secondly, let's clarify that "increments are not atomic operations" means `x++` consists of 3 atomic actions:

```java
var temp = x;     // volatile read of 'x' to local variable 'temp'
temp = temp + 1;  // increment of local variable 'temp'
x = temp;         // volatile write to `x`
```

Finally, let's rewrite

```
The most interesting result, "2" can be explained by this interleaving:
        Thread 1: (0 ------ stalled -------> 1)     (1->2)(2->3)(3->4)(4->5)
        Thread 2:   (0->1)(1->2)(2->3)(3->4)    (1 -------- stalled ---------> 2)
```

in a way that shows volatile reads and writes to `x`:

```
Thread1    Thread2
r₁₀:0                  | global
            r₂₀:0      | order of
            w₂₁:1      | volatile
            r₂₂:1      | reads
            w₂₃:2      | and
            r₂₄:2      | writes
            w₂₅:3      V
            r₂₆:3
            w₂₇:4
w₁₁:1
            r₂₈:1
r₁₂:1
w₁₃:2
r₁₄:2
w₁₅:3
r₁₆:3
w₁₇:4
r₁₈:4
w₁₉:5
            w₂₉:2
```

On this diagram:

- the global order of volatile reads and writes goes from top to bottom
- `r:1` is a volatile read of `x` which returns `1`
- `w:1` is a volatile write of `1` to `x`

Notice that:

- `w` always writes the value of the previous `r` in *the same thread* incremented by 1
- `r` always return the value written by the previous `w` in *the global order*

Now we can answer your question:

> But isn't there an execution that will produce `1`? I definitely can't think of any. But why there actually is none?

1. look at the last write in the global order `w₂₉`: it always writes (the value read by `r₂₈`)+`1`
   (BTW the last write in the global order will always be either the last write `w₁₉` in Thread1 or the last write  `w₂₉` in Thread2; in this case it's `w₂₉`, but for `w₁₉` the reasoning is the same)
2. `r₂₈` always reads the previous write in the global order, which is:

   - either `w₂₇` from the same thread
   - or some write `w₁ₓ` from Thread1 (if `w₁ₓ` happens in between `w₂₇` and `r₂₈` in runtime)

   In any case `r₂₈` always returns some previous non-initial write.
   But every non-initial write always writes at least `1`.
   That means `w₂₉` always writes at least `2`.